# Get the value of id from spans inside a div using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to get the id value from the spans.

Thanks
Jean

Answer (score 2):

```
var ids = $('div span').map(function() {
    return $(this).attr('id');
});
```

Your question isn't very clear so this is all I can come up with.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('span').each(function() {
    alert(this.id);
});
```